# Original Route parameters in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the original route parameters in a partial view, more concrete:
I have a view with following code:

```
@Html.Action("List", "Forum", new { obj = Model.Project})
```

I have a forumcontroller with following method:

```
    public PartialViewResult List(IForumTopic obj)
    {
        return PartialView(obj.ForumTopics);
    }
```

Now I want the route data of the original request:
if i use the url : /home/1/Forum/List then List is the method, 1 is the Id, and home is the controller, but if i do this:

```
ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

the value is Forum and not Home, is there a way to get Home, and the Id from de route parameters?

Comment: I found it myself, you can do the following:
this.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, it is completely valid to post it and then accept your own answer: that way it'll be easy to find when someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it myself, you can do the following: `this.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();`